# Do the words 'gift' and 'present' have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, ambiguity

As the question says, do these two words have the same meaning?

Comment: I think in verb yes.

Comment: This is a general reference question. Please look in any online dictionary the definitions for [gift](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/gift) and [present](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/present), and if you are still confused explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless like in the old TV series *Mind your Language* you say *gift* when  attendance is being called in a classroom!

In other words, *present* has other meanings, but one of its meanings is the same as *gift*

Comment: The opposite is also true. You would not say that someone has the present of the gob, for example.

Comment: Agreed, you can't say that. Gift has other meanings or nuances as well.